# How can I fix my image collision - Pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, pygame, pygame-surface

I'm pretty new to Pygame and I don't really understand collision and images. My game is a basic screen saver animation but my image bounces the wrong way when it touches the borders.

This is the image(Note: I resized the image in photoshop): https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/kN3Hrnzx2W1Fln0kkmYymfycyU3R4FCjt-3e9hGINPkblk00pEwJFbxOCJ8wW8rA6sg

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

width, height = (624, 392)
bg = (0,0,0)
img = pygame.image.load(r"C:\Users\victo\Downloads\sony_dvd.png")
win = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

pygame.display.set_caption("Screen Saver")
win.fill(bg)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

x = 0
y = 0
w = 78
h = 49
vel = 2
direct = 'se'
running = True
while running:
    clock.tick(27)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    if direct == 'nw':
        x = x - vel
        y = y - vel
        win.blit(img, (x, y))
        if x <= 10:
            direct = 'sw'
        elif y <= 10:
            direct = 'ne'
    if direct == 'ne':
        x = x + vel
        y = y - vel
        win.blit(img, (x, y))
        if x >= 614 - w:
            direct = 'nw'
        elif y <= 10:
            direct = 'se'
    if direct == 'sw':
        x = x - vel
        y = y + vel
        win.blit(img, (x, y))
        if x <= 10:
            direct = 'se'
        elif y >= 392 - h:
            direct = 'nw'
    if direct == 'se':
        x = x + vel
        y = y + vel
        win.blit(img, (x, y))
        if x >= 614 - w:
            direct = 'sw'
        elif y >= 382 - h:
            direct = 'ne'

    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Your original question asked about ghost images on the screen, which is what was answered. If after you get an answer you have another question, you shouldn't edit and change the question, but instead ask a new question.

Comment: You edited and changed the question after getting an answer to the original question of why you were getting ghost trails behind the image. Normally I believe this is not considered good form and so would not answer the revised question. However you are new and the issue is a simple typo so I addressed it anyway. I edited my answer to show you the typo. Please next time ask a second question rather than changing the original question.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing gets drawn on the screen that you do not draw, and conversely everything you draw on the screen stays there unless you draw over it.

You are getting after images of the things you draw because the old images drawn are still on the screen.

The easiest way to stop that is to `fill(bg)` the screen each frame (at the start of your loop) before you redraw the images.

```py
while running:
    clock.tick(27)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    win.fill(bg) # <--- add this here
```

There are other ways, but that is the simplest for someone starting out.

A more complicated approach is just to draw over the area that your moved image used to cover with a section of the background, but for most simple situations just redrawing the entire thing is easier.

Edit:

The OP edited and changed the question after getting an answer to the original question of why it was getting ghost trails behind the image. Normally I believe this is not considered good form and so would not answer the revised question, however the OP is new and the issue is a simple typo so I will address it anyway.

There is a small typo in the code which is why it is bouncing the wrong way of some of the edges. You have the `ne` and `sw` flipped in the `nw` check. This:

```py
    if direct == 'nw':
        x = x - vel
        y = y - vel
        win.blit(img, (x, y))
        if x <= 10:
            direct = 'sw'
        elif y <= 10:
            direct = 'ne'
```

should be:

```py
        if direct == 'nw':
            x = x - vel
            y = y - vel
            win.blit(img, (x, y))
            if x <= 10:
                direct = 'ne'
            elif y <= 10:
                direct = 'sw'
```

Answer (score 0):

win.fill(bg) needs to go inside while loop.

Comment: but how do I fix my collision?

Comment: You need to use pygame Rectangle objects. It's easy to do, but you need to see how it is done once or twice before the method makes intuitive sense. In video games, you know about "hit-boxes"? That's what the rectangles are. Basically you handle two sets of objects at the same time. One is a set of images to draw on the screen, the other is the set of rectangles that are the same size as those images. You watch the rectangles as things move on the screen and those rectangles will tell you when a collision occurs. I will post an example for you if someone doesn't beat me to it. It's easy.

Comment: Oh, Glenn Mackintosh has a point. Each thread needs to have a single question. If you have a new question, you need to start a new thread. But there are plenty of tutorials out there. Do a search for "using pygame rectangles to detect collisions." I've discontinued work on my example. Sorry. Good luck.

Comment: PS: Pygame rectangles are SO MUCH more than collision detectors. They can handle a lot of the things you do manually in your code and can be used to simplify placement of images on surfaces like the screen. You owe it to yourself to make a study of them.